# How do I submit and save a Child form with the Parent as nested fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, simple-form

Suppose you have the following `Child` class:

```
Child < AR
 belongs_to :parent
end
```

Which is associated to a `Parent` class:

```
Parent < AR
 has_many :children
end
```

I'd like to create a form within an action/view of the `ChildrenController` that allows the user to create a new `Child` and a new `Parent` if none has been assigned (I don't wan't a `ParentsController` since it doesn't have the same relevance to the application).

I've created a simple form in the new.haml.html view:

```
= simple_form @child do |c|
  c.input :field_for_child
  c.association :parent do |p|
    p.input :field_for_parent
```

The result is a params hash that looks like `"child" => { "field_for_child" => "value1", "parent" => { "field_for_parent:  => "value2" } }`

How can I do to save "child" and "parent" in as fewer lines as possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
@child.parent_id = (params[:parent][:field_for_parent]) || Parent.create(...).id
```

That'd be my educated guess... Where "(...)" would be your arguments for the new parent

Answer (score 0):

in your model you write

```
class Child < AR
  belongs_to :parent
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :parent
end
```

and then inside your controller you can just save the child using the given attributes.